# Dart Formatter Weirdness

Tags: flutter, dart, formatter

I think dart formatter is not working right. As an example:

`controller2.animateToPage(frameworksPage, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 480), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);`

formats as:

```
controller2.animateToPage(
                          frameworksPage,
                          duration: const Duration(
                          milliseconds: 480),
                          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
```

and it gets even worse when it gets to if statements.
Is there a solution for this bs?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no syntax errors somewhere in the same file. The formatter sometimes stops working if there are syntax errors.

I tried to reproduce the problem, but the formatter worked just fine:

```dart
    final PageController controller2 = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    final frameworksPage = 1;
    controller2.animateToPage(frameworksPage,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 480),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
```

However, I suggest adding a trailing comma behind the `curve` parameter, it leads to better alignment of braces.

```dart
    final PageController controller2 = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    final frameworksPage = 1;
    controller2.animateToPage(
      frameworksPage,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 480),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
```

This is my personal preference, though.

Comment: also noteworthy is, that the very-good-analysis package adds a linter rule that checks for that missing trailing comma.

Comment: Yes, I can absolutely recommend very-good-analysis. Thanks for adding this hint.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `,` behind `Curves.fastOutSlowIn` and it should look a little better. Also maybe you have the maximum line length set very low so it might wrap to the next line a little to early